# Printer Samsung m2070

Tags: samsung

Howsit,

I have installed the drivers for the my printer, however the generic list of printers is not on there. I installed Samsung ML-1660, 2.0.0 for my Samsung m 2070f. It works as far as printing but my printer wont find my laptop so I can scan documents to it.

What is the best way around this ?

Answer (score 0):

To get the scanner working, install the samsung linux driver for the scanner (install-scanner.sh), and then use the Ubuntu provided "Simple Scan" to scan documents.

The printer will not "see" the laptop, but the laptop will "see" the scanner.